# javascript variable outside function (with async/await)?

Tags: javascript

I have following code which doesn't work due to syntax error (await outside an async function)

1. how do I define a variable with await and export it?
2. When I define a variable like this and import it from other files, does the variable gets created only once (when file is first read?) or gets created everytime when it's imported?

Code..

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import remoteConfig from '@react-native-firebase/remote-config'

class RemoteConfig {
  constructor() {
    if (__DEV__) {
      //Fetch, no cache. activate
      remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate(0)
    } else {
      //Fetch, cache for 5 minutes and activate
      remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate()
    }
  }

  static async build() {
    await remoteConfig().setConfigSettings({
      minimumFetchIntervalMillis: 300000,
    })

    return new RemoteConfig()
  }

  setDefaults(defaults) {
    remoteConfig().setDefaults(defaults)
  }

  getValues(keys) {
    return _.pick(remoteConfig().getAll(), keys)
  }

  getValue(key) {
    return remoteConfig().getValue(key)
  }
}

export let firebaseConfig = await RemoteConfig.build()
```

I'm using it with `import {firebaseConfig} from path/to/thefile`

Comment: @yash I think you're looking to use a singleton pattern. since you're already using async functions inside your constructor, why not just call your build() method from there and just export a single instance of your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `await` can be only used in `async` function. It's not possible to export a variable with `await` syntax.
2. Since the export with `await` is not possible, it's difficult to say if the `RemoteConfig.build()` will be called each time.
   If we assume, you wrote `firebaseConfig = RemoteConfig.build();`. The function will be called one time when the module is evaluated.

Here is a workaround:

You can define a function to set the `firebaseConfig` and call it at the time of app start.

So:

```js
export let firebaseConfig;

export async function setFirebaseConfig() {
    firebaseConfig = await RemoteConfig.build();
}
```

This will allow you to not call the `RemoteConfig.build()` more than once. Also the `firebaesConfig` can be exported without `await` syntax.

Comment: if OP was not looking to execute a function in the import, could an async self invoking function be used in its stead?

Comment: `RemoteConfig.build()` won't be evaluated multiple times. Module code is evaluated first time when it is imported, then the same exports returned to all importers.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `OP was not looking to execute a function in the import`

Comment: @yash what i mean is that you'll have to execute `setFirebaseConfig()` inside the file you're importing the function from and it will also have to be used inside of an async/await context, or use promise chains.

Comment: I dont think so. Because if he imports the config from a child component, the function will be called each time the component appears. Just calling it at app bootstrap will initialize the firebaseConfig and it can be used across the app.

Comment: if I had the variable defined without `await`, would it be created multiple times or only once at module loading?

Comment: @eugene, it's only once.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you have to wait for the ["Top-level `await`" proposal (currently at Stage 3)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), that allows doing so (with a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), you can use it now). It would allow exactly the same code that you have.

Until then, the only way to achieve a variable to exported like this to make the variable's value a promise, that all importers have to await on its own.